# How do you enter data in PlistBuddy

Tags: terminal, plistbuddy

I am trying to change a data value with PlistBuddy and can't figure it out.

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :Kernel:Emulate:Cpuid1Mask AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAA==" ~/Desktop/test.plist

Instead of writing the data I want, when I view the file, I get: QUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQ0FBQUFBQT09

I have played with hex, dec, bin, everything I can think of, but it never writes correctly.
I have been searching everywhere, and there's nothing I can find that explains how to do it. Everything is on entering strings, and nothing tells how to enter data, or it's format.

I need to change that value back and forth from AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAA== to AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==

I tried printing it to see the output, so I could see the format, but it's blank in terminal.

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I don't know if this can even be done. I have been trying for days, and nobody can figure it out. Is there syntax for PlistBuddy to take hex? If I print it, it won't show in terminal, because they are invisible characters, so there's not going to be any way to enter them in a command line. If there's another built in command to do it, please let me know. I just need to manipulate that value.

Comment: I can get it in correctly using string instead, so is there a way to put it in as a string, then change the string tag to a data tag?

Answer (score 1):

`PlistBuddy` can do it with the help of `base64`. First decode your incoming Base64 stream into binary data.

```
base64 -D <<< AAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAA== > /tmp/tmp.bin
```

Then use `PlistBuddy`'s `Import` command.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Import :Kernel:Emulate:Cpuid1Mask /tmp/tmp.bin" ~/Desktop/test.plist
```

Delete your binary data if not needed anymore.

```
rm /tmp/tmp.bin
```

PS: I am using this frequently to change data values in OpenCore.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Both defaults and PlistBuddy cannot do it.
plutil works fine without corrupting the data string.

Comment: haven't been here in a while, thought I would share the solution I found. As I said above, both "defaults" and "PlistBuddy" can't do it. Either a bug, or oversight. It's weird that they can read the string, just not write.
I ended up using "plutil":
plutil -replace Kernel.Emulate.Cpuid1Mask -data "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==" /config.plist